# Int from NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSData object with 4 bytes length. I know this 4 bytes construcuts a positive integer. How should I get the int from those NSdata object?

Comment: Is the 4-byte value a 32-bit number, or 4 ASCII digits?  E.g. would 4321 be 0x000010E1 (32-bit big-endian number) or 0x34333231 ("4321"in ASCII).  If it's a number, is it signed (int32_t) or unsigned (uint32_t)?  Is it big endian or little endian (or same as the running system)?

Comment: I have found the solution here.

char buffer[4];
   [data getBytes:buffer length:4];
   
      int dataSize = 0;
   char cBuf2[4];
   for(int k=0;k < 4; ++k)
   {
    cBuf2[k] = buffer[3-k];
   }
   memcpy(&dataSize, cBuf2, 4);
   
   NSLog(@"Zip stream size :%d", dataSize);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution here.

```
char buffer[4]; 

[data getBytes:buffer length:4]; 

int dataSize = 0; 

char cBuf2[4]; 

for(int k=0;k < 4; ++k) {

 cBuf2[k] = buffer[3-k]; 

} 

memcpy(&dataSize, cBuf2, 4); 

NSLog(@"Zip stream size :%d", dataSize);
```

Answer (score 12):

If you know the endianness matches the current system:

```
x = *(const UInt32 *)[theData bytes];
```

If you know the endianness is backwards, follow that with:

```
x = Endian32_Swap( x );
```

If you are not sure of the source and target endianness, you should probably find another way to pass the data.

Comment: You can use `EndianU32_BtoN` (or `EndianS32_BtoN` for signed) if you know the source is big-endian, and `EndianU32_LtoN` if you know it's little-endian.  This means you don't have to know the endianness of the running system.

Comment: - (void) onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{

//I know this data is 4bytes length
NSString *msgReceived = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

//I want to get the int from the NSData

}

Answer (score 3):

```
int32_t value; // make unsigned if needed. 
[myData getBytes: &value];
```

Comment: `getBytes:` is deprecated in OS X 10.6 and iPhone OS 4.0, so one may use [`getBytes:length:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes:length:) to avoid warnings.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
but this return a huge integer value like 865465934. I have stuck with this for almost 1 day now.

Comment: @charith, it sounds like the endianness is wrong, try swapping it with [`NSSwapLittleIntToHost`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSwapLittleIntToHost)

Comment: @charith, see my comment above.  It will help if you give more info.

Comment: @dreamlax, I'm trying. I will let you know the results for sure. Thanks again.

Comment: - (void) onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
//I know this data is 4bytes length
NSString *msgReceived = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

//I want to get the int from the NSData

}