# Convert Hex NSData to int in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, hex, nsdata

Our custom Smart Router is giving me `NSData` response

> <800c01ff 0001ffff ffff29ff>

Here, `800c` is my deviceId. How to convert it to `int` ?

> deviceId =32780;

When I send command to router I constructed it like,

```
Byte mqttData[12];

mqttData[0] =[[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:(deviceID >> 8) & 0xFF] intValue];
//mqttData[0]=128 or 80 in Hex

mqttData[1] =[[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:deviceID & 0xFF] intValue];
//mqttData[1]=12 or 'C' in Hex

return [NSData dataWithBytes:mqttData length:sizeof(mqttData)];
```

Comment: Use `NSData *deviceIDData = [theDataResponse subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)], int deviceId; [deviceIDData getBytes:&deviceId length:sizeof(int)];` ?

Comment: Why is `NSNumber` involved at all?

Comment: @Lamre deviceId : 5508224. but it was 32780

Comment: @Lamre deviceIDData <800c> deviceId : 3200

Comment: `int deviceId = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(*(int*)([deviceIDData bytes]));`

Comment: @Lamre yeah :), Done :), Thanks man :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NSData to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332641/converting-nsdata-to-int) Except that it's `CFSwapInt16BigToHost` instead of `CFSwapInt32BigToHost`, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int deviceId = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(*(int*)([deviceIDData bytes]))
```

Answer taken from Larme's comment.