# Iterate over byte array to parse out individual lengths

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am reading data off of a hardware device through Core Bluetooth (BLE). One of the charecteristics I am reading is a struct compressed down to a single value. The struct as programmed to the board looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8          id;
  uint32        dur;
  uint16        dis;
} record;
```

Most of the other characteristics I am parsing are of a single type, `uint8`, `uint32`, so on.

How can I loop through the bytes and parse each individual characteristic either to native type or an `NSString`? Is there a way to iterate over the bytes or substring the `NSData` object?

```
NSData *data = [characteristic value]; // characteristic is of type CBCharacteristic
    NSUInteger len = data.length;
    Byte *bytes = (Byte *)[data bytes];
    for (Byte in bytes) { // no fast enumeration here, but the general intention is to iterate byte by byte
        // TODO: parse out uint8
        // TODO: parse out uint32
        // TODO: parse out uint16
    }
```

Comment: If the struct is always that fixed layout then simply access the bytes directly - [data bytes][0] will be your id.  [data bytes[1]]-[data bytes[4] will be dur and bytes 5 & 6 will be dis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to create an instance of your struct from the data.

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8          id;
  uint32        dur;
  uint16        dis;
} record;

@implementation YourClass (DataRetrieval)
- (void)process:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {
  record r;
  [[characteristic value] getBytes:&r length:sizeof(r)];
  // r.id
  // r.dur
  // r.dis
}
@end
```

Comment: The struct exists on the board, or device, I am connecting to. It is pushed over bluetooth as a single data object. There isn't automatic parsing of that data to an NSObject or struct, the mapping has to be done manually, which is why I am trying to iterate over the data object.

Comment: You must know the format of the data you are getting back if you are planning to parse it though, right? Just define a struct in your code that matches that format.

Comment: Maybe the knowledge he's missing is that the struct he has used in his example will work as-is in Objective-C.

Comment: @ilrugel the answer is a bit unclear on that, but in Objective-C you can use C structs as well. Just define the same struct `record` in the code of your iOS app and use it like in dan's answer: after calling `getBytes:length` on an instance of `NSData`, all the fields in `record` struct will be assigned the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating across your data, and if you want to pull out individual values you use subDataWithRange of the Characteristic NSData.

Something like...

```
    //create test data as an example.
    unsigned char bytes[STRUCT_SIZE] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x0, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03};
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

    //assume that you have a packed structure and endianess is correct
    //[0] = id
    //[1] = dur
    //[2] = dur
    //[3] = dur
    //[4] = dur
    //[5] = dis
    //[6] = dis

    assert(STRUCT_SIZE == [data length]);

    uint8_t     idu = *( uint8_t*)[[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] bytes];
    uint32_t    dur = *(uint32_t*)[[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)] bytes];
    uint16_t    dis = *(uint16_t*)[[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)] bytes];

    assert(1 == idu);
    assert(2 == dur);
    assert(3 == dis);
```

A good description of the [approach is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332641/converting-nsdata-to-int)

And an approach for [endianness is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098808/int-from-nsdata)

I am also not sure if you are [doing any Structure Packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)